# How to load captcha script to CI?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have captcha script (image.php) which generate image:

```
<img src="/application/libraries/captcha/image.php" onclick="javascript:reloadCaptcha()" id="captcha" title="Click to reload image" alt="Click to reload image">
```

Question: how can I load this image?

Direct access to example.com/application/libraries/captcha/image.php — 403 error.

Captcha site: http://www.php-help.ro/php-tutorials/math-capcha-image-against-spam/

Answer (score 1):

Ci have its own library for captcha ....you can have look on this http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition of Pramod response, if you still want to use the captcha in that tutorial, you can load external classes as libraries in CI with:

```
this->load->libray('my_captha');
```

you need to create a php file containing the class, put it in application/libraries and load it, once you have loaded the library you can use:

```
this->my_captcha->my_method_to_generate_captcha();
```